# How to set different CSS colors for code block and inline respectively?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am writing in Wordpress, and would like to set different colors for code blocks vs inline code.

Currently I am using this snippet, but this will change both my code block vs inline code style together.

```css
pre {
    background: #f4f4f4;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-left: 3px solid #097969;
    border-right: 3px solid #097969;
    border-top: 3px solid #097969;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #097969;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #666;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    margin-bottom: 1.6em;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 1em 1.5em;
    display: block;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

More specifically, I expect `inline code` to have different color settings from:

```py
code block
```

Comment: FYI; 'border' above is redundant by virtue of the four 'border-'s

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure I understand what you are trying to do.

However, if you use CSS attribute selectors you can set the colours as you wish. Note that you will need to set the style.display with in line HTML though. You cannot set it in CSS when using attribute selectors if you want to select it as an attribute value of the attribute style.  See the code below.

CSS

```
<style>
pre[style*="display: block"] {
  background-color: pink;
}
pre[style*="display: inline"] {
  background-color: wheat;
}
pre {
  border: 3px solid #097969;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.6;
}
</style>
```

HTML

```
<body>
<pre style="display: inline">
An inline code block.
</pre>
<pre style="display: block">
A block code block.
</pre>
<pre style="display: inline">
Another inline code block.
</pre>
<pre style="display: block">
Another block code block.
</pre>
</body>
```